# Change Color Alpha with Timer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms app which the user can choose a color from the color picker.
(I'm using the color Dialog from the Toolbox).

Now when the user chose some color I'm painting some shapes on the form using the GDI
and bitmap.
Is it possible to change this color's alpha with a timer?

because all I see is the color Dialog returns a Color or just the current values of 
A,R,G,B (alpha,red,green,blue) and those values cannot be set programmatically .

I know there is `Color.FromArgb()` method. 
I thought about this code :

```
Color userColor = colorsDialog.Color;
Color c = Color.FromArgb(alphaValue,userColor);
```

When the alphaValue is set to zero, and on each timer tick incrementing it by 1.
but it doesn't work..

Edit: the shape is drawn on the bitmap.

Comment: Are you repainting on each click?

Comment: Im refreshing the form on each timer tick, so the Form's paint method is called when the refresh occurs

Comment: Next run in the debugger, set a breapoint in the OnPaint method, and check what Color is being used to paint the shapes with varible alpha.

Comment: actually is kind of game, so the shapes is drawn on a bitmap and than i'm drawing the bitmap on the form. so is this cause the problem?

Comment: Probably, unless you are also redrawing the bitmap on each repaint.

Comment: I'm drawing the bitmap on the Paint method, and when the refresh occurs it calls the paint method to repaint the new state of the bitmap..

Comment: Just to clarify - Are you redrawing the shapes to the bitmap, and also redrawing the bitmap to the screen, on each OnPaint?

Comment: right now I didn't, I thought about to do it.. 
I have some shapes, each shape have its position, now when the user choose to move some shape Im redrawing the shape on the bitmap - to save the current state of the bitmap and then redrawing the bitmap on the form - I saw this technique in some tutorial..
Now I want to add a fade in effect.. so I thought to do it in the way I described above

Comment: Always remember - the computer is a very fast idiot. If you tell it to redraw the bitmap, it redraws the OLD bitmap. It won't draw the new bitmap, with the new alpha, unless you tell it to redraw the NEW bitmap.

Comment: I guess you're right! thanks! I'll let you know if I solved it